# process two kafka queues such that only process the data which is present in both queue

Tags: apache-kafka

I have three different services: service1, service2 and service3. service3 can only process data which are processed by service1 and service2. From a source stream I am sending data to a kafka queue, each data in the queue has unique id. service1 and service2 consumes that data and send the processed data to queue1 and queue2 respectively.

Now, I need a service which will fetch only those messages which are present in both queue1 and queue2 and send it to a different queue where service3 will process them.

FYI, service1 and service2 takes different time to process a message. I want to process the message by service3 as soon as they are processed by service1 and service2. Also, I can't run service1 and service2 in sequential order, I have to run them independently only.

Below is pictorial representation. I need to build code for "some service?". Preferred language is python or node.
[image]

Comment: Kafka clients can subscribe to multiple topics, yes. Is that your question? If you want to join/window records that only exist in both topics, then Node/Python don't have good options for that, and you probably want to use 2 partitions of a single topic rather than 2 topics (meaning you don't really need service1 and service2 since you could partition from the beginning)

Comment: I need both service1 and service2. Basically, service1 calculate score on data, lets say score1. similarly service2 calculates different score i.e. score2. and service 3 use both score1 and score2 to give final score.

Comment: Okay, well, as mentionted, you need some type of windowing that would consume a score value, then wait for the other to arrive. You will also want to maintain that source document ID on both scores

Comment: yes. send only documents to service3 only when it is processed by both service1 and service2. If a doc is processed by service1 and service2 is still processing or waiting to process it then dont send that doc to service3 untill it is processed by service2. And each doc has unique id.